# RecyclerView with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use the new `RecyclerView` widget inside a `Fragment` but I am getting this error:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MyActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

What am I doing wrong?

This is my `Fragment`:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerviewFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerviewAdapter mRecyclerviewAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    private List<ViewModel> viewModel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(viewModel);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerviewAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}
```

And my Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private List<ViewModel> viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        RecyclerviewFragment recyclerviewFragment = new RecyclerviewFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, recyclerviewFragment).commit();

        viewModel.add(new ViewModel("View"));



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have not created the object for viewModel and that's why the error.

Comment: Please - you just had a silly Java programming problem where you forgot to initialize a variable. This does not help anybody (except you) Please remove this question as people end up here that really have problems with RecyclerViews and Fragments! Thank you for your cooperation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize `private List<ViewModel> viewModel`